# If I check 2 input radio the disabled Submit button enables, but if I uncheck them...the Submit button doesn't disable back

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button, form-submit

I just need a little help with this code.

```
var prv3;
var markIt3 = function(e) {
  if (prv3 === this && this.checked) {
    this.checked = false;
    prv3 = null; 
  } else {
    prv3 = this;
    }   
};
$(function() {
  $('input.class_x').on('click', markIt3);
});

$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {

  var current = $('input.class_x').filter(':checked');
  var sbmtBtn = document.getElementById('SubmitButton');
  sbmtBtn.disabled = true;

  if (current.length > 1) {
    sbmtBtn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    sbmtBtn.disabled = true;
  }
}).change();
```

My request is the following:
can anybody just FIX what is missing in order for the form Submit button to go back to be disabled as it is supposed to be, because this form only enables it when 2 input type radio have been checked?

This form previous description is the main idea of everything:

A form, with several input type radios. Check at least 2 and the Submit button enables. But if you uncheck any of them, the Submit button should disable back, but I cannot manage to achieve this PART. 
I just need a little HELP with IT, nothing else.

Please, DON'T change my code too much!Can it be done?

Check the fiddle right here: https://jsfiddle.net/Suiberu/70tkgk5t/13/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually problem is deselecting radio button not detected as a change. How about this

```js
var prv3;
var markIt3 = function(e) {
  if (prv3 === this && this.checked) {
    this.checked = false;
    prv3 = null; 
  } else {
    prv3 = this;
   }
  checkIfValid();
};
$(function() {
  $('input.class_x').on('click', markIt3);
});

function checkIfValid() {
  var current = $('input.class_x').filter(':checked');
  var sbmtBtn = document.getElementById('SubmitButton');
  sbmtBtn.disabled = true;

  if (current.length > 1) {
    sbmtBtn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    sbmtBtn.disabled = true;
  }
};
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

input[type='submit']:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myform" autocomplete="off" method="post">
  <input class="class_x" type="radio" name="name_1" value="value_1" id="id_1" />
  <input class="class_x" type="radio" name="name_2" value="value_2" id="id_2" />
  <input class="class_x" type="radio" name="name_3" value="value_3" id="id_3" />
  <input type="submit" name="name_submit" value="OK" class="class_submit" id="SubmitButton" required/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks axcl, just adding a fiddle out from your code, if anyone wants to check
https://jsfiddle.net/Suiberu/70tkgk5t/32/

Answer (score 1):

Or you can change the type of your inputs to checkBoxes and it will simply do the magic.
Here is the  [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/buddhirameshi/70tkgk5t/29/).

```js
 var prv3;
        var markIt3 = function (e) {
            if (prv3 === this && this.checked) {
                this.checked = false;
                prv3 = null;
            } else {
                prv3 = this;
            }
        };
        $(function () {
            $('input.class_x').on('click', markIt3);
        });

    
        $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
          
            var current = $('input.class_x').filter(':checked');
            var sbmtBtn = document.getElementById('SubmitButton');
            sbmtBtn.disabled=true;

            if (current.length > 1) {
                sbmtBtn.disabled = false;
            } else {
                sbmtBtn.disabled = true;
            }
         
            
        }).change();
```

```css
   input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

input[type='submit']:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myform" autocomplete="off" method="post">
       <input class="class_x" type="checkbox" name="name_1" value="value_1" id="id_1" />
  <input class="class_x" type="checkbox" name="name_2" value="value_2" id="id_2" />
  <input class="class_x" type="checkbox" name="name_3" value="value_3" id="id_3" />
        <input type="submit" name="name_submit" value="OK" class="class_submit" id="SubmitButton" required />
    </form>
```

Only the type has been changed from radio button to checkbox.

Comment: but I need radio buttons ;(

Comment: Glad you've got an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.prop()` function instead

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  var current = $('input.class_x').filter(':checked');

  var $sbmtBtn = $('#SubmitButton');
  $sbmtBtn.prop('disabled', true);

  if (current.length > 1) {
    $sbmtBtn.prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $sbmtBtn.prop('disabled', true);
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" class="class_x">
  <input type="radio" class="class_x">
  <input id="SubmitButton" type="submit">
</form>
```

[.prop() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.checked = false
```

..does not fire the change event, so the change code doesn't get fired when a radio button is unchecked.

Add the following line of code after that line:

```
$(this).change();
```

That will fire the change code.